# How to colour background on a scatterplot using ggplot but still show data points in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

This is my first question here so hope this makes sense and thank you for your time in advance!

I am trying to generate a scatterplot with the data points being the log2 expression values of genes from 2 treatments from an RNA-Seq data set. With this code I have generated the plot below:

```
   ggplot(control, aes(x=log2_iFGFR1_uninduced, y=log2_iFGFR4_uninduced)) + 
       geom_point(shape = 21, color = "black", fill = "gray70") +
       ggtitle("Uninduced iFGFR1 vs Uninduced iFGFR4 ") +
       xlab("Uninduced iFGFR1") + 
       ylab("Uninduced iFGFR4") +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-15,15,by = 1)) +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-15,15,by = 1)) +
       geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = 1, color="blue", size = 1) +
       geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, colour = "black", size = 1) +
       geom_abline(intercept = -1, slope = 1, colour = "red", size = 1) + 
       theme_classic() + 
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Current scatterplot:

[image]

However, I would like to change the background of the plot below the red line to a lighter red and above the blue line to a lighter blue, but still being able to see the data points in these regions. I have tried so far by using polygons in the code below.

```
    pol1 <- data.frame(x = c(-14, 15, 15), y = c(-15, -15, 14))
    pol2 <- data.frame(x = c(-15, -15, 14), y = c(-14, 15, 15))

    ggplot(control, aes(x=log2_iFGFR1_uninduced, y=log2_iFGFR4_uninduced)) + 
       geom_point(shape = 21, color = "black", fill = "gray70") +
       ggtitle("Uninduced iFGFR1 vs Uninduced iFGFR4 ") +
       xlab("Uninduced iFGFR1") + 
       ylab("Uninduced iFGFR4") +
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-15,15,by = 1)) +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-15,15,by = 1)) +
       geom_polygon(data = pol1, aes(x = x, y = y), color ="pink1") +
       geom_polygon(data = pol2, aes(x = x, y = y), color ="powderblue") +
       geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = 1, color="blue", size = 1) +
       geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, colour = "black", size = 1) +
       geom_abline(intercept = -1, slope = 1, colour = "red", size = 1) + 
       theme_classic() + 
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

New scatterplot:

[image]

However, these polygons hide my data points in this area and I don't know how to keep the polygon color but see the data points as well. I have also tried adding "fill = NA" to the geom_polygon code but this makes the area white and only keeps a colored border. Also, these polygons shift my axis limits so how do I change the axes to begin at -15 and end at 15 rather than having that extra unwanted length?

Any help would be massively appreciated as I have struggled with this for a while now and asked friends and colleagues who were unable to help.

Thanks,

Liv

Comment: Simply plot the points at last, i.e. change the order of the geoms so that geom_point is called after geom_ploygons and geom_ablines

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks so much for your reply. I've changed that round and that has solved the issue of the not being able to see the points! However, I can't seem to get rid of the unwanted extra length on the axes past -15 and 15 on either end. I have tried using + ylim(-15,15) + xlim(-15,15) but I get this error "Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale." Hope you can help and thanks so much again!!

Comment: Hi @livm1234.  Answer to the second part of your question is to use the "long form" of `xlim` and `ylim`: `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous`.  They have the argument `expand=` that notes how much the axis is "expanded out" before you reach the edge of the plot area or the axes.  See the answer posted for full information.  Oh, and welcome to SO and congrats on your first question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has two parts, so I'll answer each in turn using a dummy dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20,5,1), y=rnorm(20,5,1))
```

### Stop geom_polygon from hiding geom_point

Stefan had commented with the answer to this one.  Here's an illustration.  Order of operations matters in `ggplot`.  The plot you create is a result of each geom (drawing operation) performed in sequence.  In your case, you have `geom_polygon` after `geom_point`, so it means that it will plot *on top* of `geom_point`.  To have the points plotted on top of the polygons, just have `geom_point` happen after `geom_polygon`.  Here's  an illustrative example:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw()
p + geom_point() + xlim(0,10) + ylim(0,10)
```

[image]

Now if we add a `geom_rect` after, it hides the points:

```
p + geom_point() +
    geom_rect(ymin=0, ymax=5, xmin=0, xmax=5, fill='lightblue') +
    xlim(0,10) + ylim(0,10)
```

[image]

The way to prevent that is to just reverse the order of `geom_point` and `geom_rect`.  It works this way for all `geoms`.

```
p + geom_rect(ymin=0, ymax=5, xmin=0, xmax=5, fill='lightblue') +
    geom_point() +
    xlim(0,10) + ylim(0,10)
```

[image]

### Removing whitespace between the axis and limits of the axis

The second part of your question asks about how to remove the white space between the edges of your `geom_polygon` and the axes.  Notice how I have been using `xlim` and `ylim` to set limits?  It is a shortcut for `scale_x_continuous(limits=...)` and `scale_y_continuous(limits=...)`; however, we can use the argument `expand=` within `scale_...` functions to set how far to "expand" the plot before reaching the axis.  You can set the expand setting for upper and lower axis limits independently, which is why this argument expects a two-component number vector, similar to the `limits=` argument.

Here's how to remove that whitespace:

```
p + geom_rect(ymin=0, ymax=5, xmin=0, xmax=5, fill='lightblue') +
geom_point() +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,10), expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10), expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi chemdork123. Your explanation is so clear and I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this. I'm new to R so I didn't realise about the order of commands mattering. I've just changed my code with your suggestions and it's worked!!!! I hope to one day be the one answering questions on SO haha!! Thank you so much for your help!! Liv

Comment: Glad to help and happy to see it worked out for you.  Order of operations does not always matter in r, but it's the case for `ggplot` for the *drawing* functions - the geoms and anything that results in plotting your data.  The one part that doesn't really matter is when you adjust theme elements with `theme_XX()` for the named themes or `theme(...)` for theme element adjustments.  I think  it's because "draw the plot area stuff" is baked into the way `ggplot` works, so the function "draw the plot area stuff for me now" is not something you call explicitly in normal plotting.